# How to select arduino 101 in ubuntu?

Tags: arduino-ide, ubuntu, 101

How to I select arduino 101? I  have ubuntu.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In that ancient version of the IDE? You don't.

You download and install the latest version of the IDE from the Arduino website, then use the Boards Manager to install the packages that include the Ardiuno 101.

Comment: This is ubuntu, most of the software is older... I don't know!

Comment: There hasn't been a new package submitted to the repos for decades. You download it manually from Arduino.cc

Comment: I had the same problem in Gentoo - also had to instal Arduino manually, but it is easy, so do not worry about it and just do it :)

Answer (score 1):

The default serial port it shows up in for me is *ttyACM0*

You can set this as your default port, so when you open the IDE with `sudo arduino`

```
~ $ vim ~/.arduino/preferences.txt
```

change the value for `serial.port`

```
serial.port=ttyACM0
```